# In perforce, how can I reopen all elements of a CL into the default CL ?

Tags: perforce

Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)

Hi:

Let's say I have a pending changelist 123 which has these 2 files...

```
... //foo/somewhere/abc.txt#100 edit
... //foo/somewherelse/def/txt#67 edit
```

I want to put both of these in the default CL.  I know I can

```
"p4 reopen -c default //foo/somewhere/abc.txt"
```

and then

```
"p4" reopen -c default //foo/somewherelse/def.txt"
```

But is there a way to specify all the files in CL 123 regardless of the paths (do both reopens with one command)?

My actual situation involves a shelvelist.  I want to put the changes in a  shelvelist back in the default CL then delete the shelvelist AND the changelist that results after one deletes a shelve.  Basically I want to undo the shelve operation.  My method of doing this is...

```
1) delete the shelve
2) p4 describe the changelist
3) p4 reopen -c default each file, one at a time
4) delete the empty changelist
```

If there's a shortcut to do that, I'm all ears (eyes, whatever) !

But I would still like to learn how to do what I originally asked.

BTW, I do NOT have admin privs :-}

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case of undoing a shelve operation and putting the shelf's contents back into the default changelist you could use `p4 revert` followed by `p4 unshelve`.

For the general case, if you just want to reopen everything in the default changelist you could do:

```
p4 reopen -c default //...
```

If you have a bunch of changelists and you want to just move the files from change 123 into the default changelist that'd be more like:

```
p4 -F %depotFile% opened -c 123 | p4 -x - reopen -c default
```

Comment: Hmmmm... piping.  Didn't think of that !
I guess I could also write a script to do these steps.  
p4 -F %depotFile% gives me a usage error...
              
    --> p4 -F %depotFile% opened -c default
    Perforce client error:
            p4 -h for usage.
            Invalid option: -F.

Comment: Update your `p4` executable to a more recent version.  I think the `-F` flag was added in 2015 or thereabouts.